# Granting aws ec2 instance access to aws secretsmanager in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am very new to terraform, but I am trying to grant this resource

```
resource aws_instance "myinstance" {
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.awsami.id}"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.my_key.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.security.my_sg_id}", "${module.security.my_security_group_id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${element(module.network.public_subnets,1)}"

  tags {
    Name = "My instance"
  }
}
```

Access to secrets manager. The instance needs to be able to read secrets via ansible script. I've found a blog on using instance profiles. How do I use an instance profile role to grant the instance access to secrets manager?

Comment: Do you know about IAM instance profiles? Also you are using older HCL1 syntax from Terraform 0.11 and below. You should consider using HCL2 syntax assuming you are using Terraform 0.12 or above. If there's a reason you have to use an older version of Terraform then you should add this to your question and include the `terraform0.11` tag.

Comment: can you link the instance profile documentation? I am very new to this field.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html would be useful to read. Then to implement with Terraform once you understand what they are you may want to see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#iam_instance_profile and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile

Comment: Cool, I will start reading through those. Maybe I'll find the answer to my question and update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by using the code below. You'll need to add `ASSUME_ROLE_POLICY_HERE` and `POLICY_GOES_HERE`. The important piece is specifying `iam_instance_profile   ="{aws_iam_instance_profile.myinstance_instance_profile.id}"`

```
locals {
 
  env_account = "${terraform.workspace}"
  
  deploy_env_name = "${lookup(var.workspace_deploy_env, local.env_account)}"

}

resource "aws_eip" "myinstanceip" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.myinstance.id}"
  vpc      = true
}

resource aws_instance "myinstance" {
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.awsami.id}"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.my_key.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.security.my_sg_id}", "${module.security.my_security_group_id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${element(module.network.public_subnets,1)}"
  iam_instance_profile   ="{aws_iam_instance_profile.myinstance_instance_profile.id}"

  tags {
    Name = "My instance"
  }
}

resource aws_route53_record "myinstance_domain_name" {
  zone_id = "${module.tf_aws_route53_zone.zone_id}"
  name    = "myinstance.${module.tf_aws_route53_zone.domain_name}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${aws_eip.myinstanceip.public_ip}"]
}

output myinstance_ip {
  value = "${aws_eip.myinstanceip.public_ip}"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "myinstance_instance_profile" {
  name = "myinstance-instance-profile"
  role = "myinstance-role"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "myinstance_role" {
  name = "myinstance-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  ASSUME_ROLE_POLICY_HERE
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "secrets_manager" {

  name        = "secrets-manager-myinstance"
  description = "Read secrets"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    POLICY_GOES_HERE
}
POLICY
}
```